# Wordpress API to get posts on a specific date

Tags: wordpress, api

I am using Wordpress for a long time and now try to get something out of its API.

I looked at https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/ and find my desired request is not there:

I want to extract posts posted on the same date (as today) but years back. For example, on Jan 8th 2019, I want to get the posts with the same date (Jan 8th) in previous years.

Now I can do a SQL and select directly from the database but I want to see if an API can do it.

Answer (score 0):

i believe what you might need is this query:

```
$date = getdate();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        'before' => array(
            'year'  => $date['year'] - 1,
            'month' => $date['mon'],
            'day'   => $date['mday']
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

This will return all post titles before 01/07/2018

Read more about date_query here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I look for posts on Jan 8th in all previous years. It is a kind of "Blog today in history" not simply blog before a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the posts just in same day on year back following code will be right :

```
 $year = date( 'Y' );
 $today = getdate();
 $args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
       array(
        'year'      => $year,
        'compare'   => '<',
       ),
        array(
          'day'      =>  $today['mday'],
          'compare'   => '=',
       ),
      array(
        'month'     =>  $today['mon'],
        'compare'   => '=',
    ),

),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ):while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
     the_title();
endwhile;endif;
```

Comment: This will return only the last year same day posts.

Comment: Do you need all the post in same day in previous all years?

Comment: Hi, changed code to get the same date in all previous years posts. Please check once whether it is working for you or not?

Comment: Thanks @tristup , but I am not inside Wordpress and would stick to API or raw SQL so I can't test your code. But thanks for the support!

Comment: even you are trying to get the posts from putside the wordpress, if you are in same root folder you can use the wordpress methods and classes here is the refernce : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files

Comment: Will try later.